# Regex to add space between capital letter, in addition to replacing the word 'And' with &

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Right now I have the replace `'And'` with `'&'` working, but I need to also add a space between a capital letter.

ex:

String: CategoryName to Category Name

and
CategoryAndName to Category & Name

Current Regex:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace( stringText, "(.+)And", "$1 & " )
```

Comment: What happens to `This And` does it become `This <extra space>And`? Also, don't use `(.+)` in your regex, use a lookbehind. `(.+)` will match all text in your string (including `And`'s) up to the very last And.

Comment: `This And` should become `This &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two regex you might need.

Using `lookbehind` it is checking whether a capital letter is just after a lowercase letter or not.

```
stringText = Regex.Replace( stringText, "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1" );
// You can also use `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` and replace with single space also.
```

And for this one it is checking whether the `And` is in between any alphabet or not using `lookbehind` and `lookahead`.

```
stringText = Regex.Replace( stringText, "(?<=[a-zA-Z])And(?=[a-zA-Z])", " & " );
```

Comment: Is it possible to have both of them in the one regex.replace

Comment: @xphong in my limited knowledge i don't know.

Comment: You've got two different replacement strings, so no, you'll have to replace all of one and then all of the other.